# What Doxygen alternative would Dave DeLong use?

Tags: objective-c, documentation

Yesterday, [Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong) answered [a question of mine](/questions/5362022/). It wasn't the answer I was looking for, but in the question he mentioned an alternative way of generating doxygen-style documentation for Objective-C.

Before I could really look into it, someone (maybe Dave himself) noticed the answer didn't match the question that well and removed it. *poof* gone was the link to that documentation tool.

I can't remember the name, but I'm fairly certain it's neither [HeaderDoc](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/headerdoc.html) nor [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) itself.

Dave, you out there? What was that link again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm clearly not Dave DeLong, but I'd use [**appledoc**](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/), it's pretty darn awesome!

Developer Page quote:

> **appledoc** is command line tool that helps Objective-C developers generate
>   Apple-like source code documentation
>   from specially formatted source code
>   comments. It's designed to take as
>   readable source code comments as
>   possible for the input and use
>   comments as well as surrounding source
>   code to generate visually appealing
>   documentation in the form of HTML as
>   well as fully indexed and browsable
>   Xcode documentation set. Although
>   there are several tools that can
>   create HTML documentation for
>   Objective-C, all of those know to me
>   fall short in meeting the minimum of
>   goals described below.
>
> **Human readable source code** appledoc is designed to keep source
>   code comments as readable as possible
>   even within your source code editor.
>
> **Cross references to objects and members** Creating cross references to
>   classes, categories or protocols is
>   straightforward and automated as much
>   as possible.
>
> **Apple-like source code HTML documentation** Generate appealing
>   HTML documentation with the same style
>   as Apple's.
>
> **Xcode documentation set creation** Generate and install fully indexed and
>   browsable Xcode documentation sets.
>   Documentation set can also be
>   automatically installed to Xcode.
>
> **Single tool from sorce code to doc set** Single tool to drive generation
>   from source code parsing to
>   documentation set installation
>
> **Easily customizable output** appledoc gives you a lot of command
>   line switches so you can parameterize
>   output. If this is not enough, you can
>   change any or all of the template
>   files to suit your needs.
>
> **100% Objective-C implementation** The whole appledoc is written in
>   Objective-C, so you can easily change
>   it using familiar language and tools.
>   This also make debugging much simpler
>   and effective.

Comment: You're too fast @Regexident, appledoc is indeed the answer yet stackoverflow makes me wait 5 more minutes before I can mark it as the correct answer :D. Will mark in five then.

Comment: Heh ;) …Give appledoc some time (it's quite a young project) and it will easily outrun Doxygen and pretty much all other existing tools as regards ObjC.